# Spring AMQP: Message Priority not working working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using Sprin AMQP's rabbittemplate to send and recieve message via RabbitMQ. I am able to send and receive messages, Howver, I want to attach priority with message.

e.g, If I am pushing 1000 messages, and let's say odd number messages have priority 1, and even number messages have priority 0, and then I am starting my consumer, then consumer should receive odd number messages first, and then even number messages.

Here is my code:
Producer:

```
public void sendMessage(int i) throws IOException {
    Record r = new Record();
    r.setFrom((i + 1));
    r.setTo("infoimage");
    r.setMessage("Hi Pritish.");
    MessageProperties prop = new MessageProperties();
    prop.setPriority(i%2);
    byte[] rByte = serialize(r);
    Message m = new Message(rByte, prop);
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, m);
}
```

Consumer:

```
public MessageListener exampleListener() {
    return new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
     //do some job
     }
```

};
   }

Am I doing something wrong? Can anybody please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to version 3.5.0, RabbitMQ [doesn't support priority out of the box](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html).

There is [a plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue), though.

You can also simulate priority by using multiple queues, but that only really works if the number of high priority messages is small, compared to low priority.

Comment: In fact, simulating priorities via extra queues works fine with a large number of messages too, but then there are no sense to do that unless you have extra resources (say, on ore more dedicated servers) to process high-priority messages.

Comment: Agreed - my point was really that "low" priority messages may still be processed ahead of high priority, if the high priority queue is deep. If you have 1000 high priority and 1 low priority, it will be processed well before the last high priority. If vice versa, the single high-priority will (likely) be processed after no more than one or two low priority.

Comment: Nice explanation. It clear my doubts. I have research on different brokers. Apache ActiveMQ supports priority queue, and try to implement it using spring. For my requirement, it somehow fits in. Thank you guys for your quick comments.

Comment: For future readers : "As of RabbitMQ 3.5.0 the priority queue is integrated into the broker; the plugin is no longer needed."